# Why blocking read() on a pty returns when process on the other end dies?

Tags: linux, tty, c, pty, pseudoterminal

When slave side of pty is not opened, `strace` on the process, which does `read(master_fd, &byte, 1);`, shows this:

```
read(3,
```

So, when nobody is connected to the slave side of pty, `read()` waits for data - it does not return with a error.

But when slave side of pty is opened by a process and that process exits, the `read()` dies with this:

```
read(3, 0xbf8ba7f3, 1)                  = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
```

The pty is created with

```
master_fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)
```

Slave side of the pty is opened with

```
comfd = open(COM_PORT, O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY)
```

Why the `read()` exits when process which opened slave side of the pty exits? Where is this described?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Linux, a `read()` on the master side of a pseudo-tty will return `-1` and set `ERRNO` to `EIO` when all the handles to its slave side have been closed, but will either block or return `EAGAIN` before the slave has been first opened.

The same thing will happen when trying to read from a slave with no master. For the master side, the condition is transient; re-opening the slave will cause a `read()` on the master side to work again.

On *BSD and Solaris the behavior is similar, with the difference that the `read()` will return `0` instead of `-1` + `EIO`. Also, on OpenBSD a `read()` will also return `0` before the slave is first opened.

I don't know if there's any standard spec or rationale for this, but it allows to (crudely) detect when the other side was closed, and simplifies the logic of programs like `script` which are just creating a pty and running another program inside it.

The solution in a program which manages the master part of a pty to which other unrelated programs can connect is to also open and keep open a handle to its slave side.

See related answer: [read(2) blocking behaviour changes when pts is closed resulting in read() returning error: -1 (EIO)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478815/read2-blocking-behaviour-changes-when-pts-is-closed-resulting-in-read-return/478969#478969)

> Why the `read()` exits when process which opened slave side of the pty exits?

When a process exits, all its file descriptors are automatically closed.